# Can I retrieve all revisions of a deleted document?

Tags: couchdb

I know I can retrieve all revisions of an "available" document, but can I retrieve the last "available" version of a deleted document?  I do not know the revision id prior to the delete.  This is the command I am currently running...it returns `{"error":"not_found","reason":"deleted"}`.

curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/test_database/a213ccad?revs_info=true

Comment: Has a database compaction been performed after the delete?

Comment: Couch's versioning is there to serve its needs, not ours.  Old versions aren't necessarily replicated, and old versions can go away during compaction.

Comment: This is not true, the last deleted version of a document is always kept to ensure consistency for replication.  Only older revisions are removed on compaction.

Answer (score 6):

I've got this problem, trying to recover deleted document, here is my solution:

0) until you run a compaction, get deleted history, e.g.:

```
curl http://example.iriscouch.com/test/_changes
```

1) you'll see deleted documents with $id and $rev, put empty document as new version, e.g.:

```
curl -X PUT http://example.iriscouch.com/test/$id?rev=$rev -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {}
```

2) now you can get all revisions info, e.g:

```
curl http://example.iriscouch.com/test/$id?revs_info=true
```

See also [Retrieve just deleted document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854883/couchdb-retrieve-just-deleted-document/10857330#10857330)

Comment: You will still see deleted documents in _changes even after a compaction. A compaction just removes non-leaf document bodies, all [well, up to revs_limit] revision metadata is preserved as well as the final deleted version(s) of a document even after compacting.

Answer (score 2):

Besides `_changes`, another good way to do this is to use `keys` with `_all_docs`:

GET `$MYDB/_all_docs?keys=["foo"]` ->

```
{
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "foo",
            "key": "foo",
            "value": {
                "deleted": true,
                "rev": "2-eec205a9d413992850a6e32678485900"
            }
        }
    ],
    "total_rows": 0
}
```

Note that it has to be `keys`; `key` will not work, because only `keys` returns info for deleted docs.

Comment: And IIUC you can POST the list of keys to the same URL, if you have a lot of keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last revision of a deleted document, however first you must first determine its revision id. To do that, you can query the [_changes](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#A_changes) feed and scan for the document's deletion record — this will contain the last revision and you can then fetch it using `docid?rev=N-XXXXX`.

I remember some mailinglist discussion of making this easier (as doing a full scan of the changes feed is obviously not ideal for routine usage), but I'm not sure anything came of it.

Comment: `/_changes` is still the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this several times recently, so for anyone else wandering by ...

This question typically results from a programming model that needs to know which document was deleted.  Since user keys such as 'type' don't survive deletion and _id is best assigned by couch, it would often be nice to peak under the covers and see something about the doc that was deleted.  An alternative is to have a process that sets deleted:True (no underscore) for documents, and to adjust any listener filters, etc., to look for deleted:True.  One of the processes can then actually delete the document.  This means that any process triggering on the document doesn't need to track an _id for eventual deletion.

Comment: You can accomplish something like this by saving the doc with _deleted:true (and any other fields you'd like to store alongside) and having the dependent processes in such a programming model just monitor _changes to do any cleanup they like in response to deletions.